# WebApi OData 4: Etag ConcurrencyCheck with offline App

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm implementing an OData V4 Service with WebApi and I'm using an int? field 'Version' on my DTOs to do OptimisticLocking when Patching entities. This is working fine.

But I think using **ETags/If-Match-Headers** instead is more elegant. Therefore I added the **[ConcurrencyCheck]** attribute to my 'Version' property. Now a **@odata.etag** information is generated based on the version field. Fine!

I use an offline-capable client to access my OData Service. Therefore I store the 'Version' information in a local db and send the stored value with every Patch request.
Of course this does not work if using Etags.
Should I store the Etag instead and send it in the header? Or is it possible to calculate the Etag from the stored version information on the client (I'm using ODataJS)?

Answer (score 0):

according to [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html), the request MUST only be processed if the specified value matches the current ETag value of the target entity, so you should store the Etag when you get this entity.
E2Etest code [there](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/tree/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/ETags) may be helpful.